# error while testing Hibernate JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I create a jUnit test to test my code, when I try to instatiate my object, I get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/cfg/SettingsFactory;)V from class org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<init>(Ejb3Configuration.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:124)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at gov.ic.isso.sentry.rest.data.CeReportDaoImpl.init(CeReportDaoImpl.java:41)
    at gov.ic.isso.sentry.rest.data.DaoBase.<init>(DaoBase.java:20)
    at gov.ic.isso.sentry.rest.data.CeReportDaoImpl.<init>(CeReportDaoImpl.java:33)
    at gov.ic.isso.sentry.rest.AppTest.testApp(AppTest.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
```

My code for my init method is

```
protected void init() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ceDataSessionData");

        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }
```

My jUnit test is as

```
 public void testApp()
    {
        CeReportDao reportDao = new CeReportDaoImpl();
        try {
            reportDao.getMoneyTransferReportJson(100, "TESTUSER1", "NS", null);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Appears to be incompatible hibernate jars in the classpath. Could you list the hibernate related jars along with their versions?

Comment: Yopu are right. That was the issue. I had a dependency project which was pulling a old version of entitiy classes for hibernate and this project was pulling the latest and hence.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread but I just thought I'd add one some extra info.  I experienced this same problem with our `Java 1.7` project using `maven 3.3.3`.

Our integration tests using `Spring 3.1.4` were working fine until I added a `hibernate-annotations (ver. 3.5.4)` dependency to one of our artifacts.  A downstream artifact then starting having the same `IllegalAccessError` mentioned above.

After spending hours trying to discover the cause of the issue, I was able to fix it by changing the hibernate-annotations dependency that I had previously added to a `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency.  This fixed the downstream integration test problems.

My only point of mentioning this was to note that at no time did I have different versions of Hibernate jars on the `classpath`.  Maven was showing all hibernate versions as 3.5.4 with the exception of a few jars that are supposed to have different versions (e.g., `hibernate-common-annotations 3.2.0`).  So, I believe the comment above about having different Hibernate jars is not the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Question has been answered by @Vikdor:

> Appears to be incompatible hibernate jars in the classpath. Could you list the hibernate related jars along with their versions?

That was the issue. I had a dependency project which was pulling a old version of entitiy classes for hibernate and this project was pulling the latest and hence.